# draw rect on image which can be resized & moved on screen using touch

Tags: iphone, image-processing, core-graphics, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

i am creating a application which provides custom image cropping….
in which user select one portion of image using rectangle which should be re-sized & can be moved as per user-touch to crop that portion……

i want rect on image so that i can crop that portion using following method

i am able to crop rect on image by following method

```
-(void) cropImage
{
   CGSize size = iv.frame.size;

   CGRect rect = CGRectMake(size.width / 4, size.height / 4, size.width/2,size.height / 2);

   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([iv.image CGImage], rect);    
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 

   CGImageRelease(imageRef);        

   // Display Image     
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];    
   [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 480.0,(size.width / 2), (size.height / 2))];    
   [scrollView addSubview:imageView]; 

   [imageView release];

   [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:imageView.frame animated:YES];

}
```

i want solution for drawing rect that can be resized by touch & moved by touch...

i am new to iPhone so....pls help me how to do that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got my answer from nice example form this link [Image Cropper](https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper)..

if anyone have better than this please pot it here....if it deserve that i will accept that answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach using a `UILongGesture` with 2 fingers. The selection rectangle is confined to the touches. SelectionView is a `UIView` initially hidden.

This is the initialization of the gesture in the `UIViewController`:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *twoFingerLongGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerLongGesture:)];
[twoFingerLongGesture setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerLongGesture];
```

And this is the gesture's handling:

```
- (void)handleTwoFingerLongGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {
            NSLog(@"mainView 2FingerLONG - UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
            CGPoint p1 = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
            CGPoint p2 = [sender locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];
            [self updateFrameSelectionWithPoint1:p1 point2:p2];
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:selectionView];
            selectionView.hidden = NO;
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {
            NSLog(@"mainView 2FingerLONG - UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged");
            CGPoint p1 = [sender locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
            CGPoint p2 = [sender locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.view];
            [self updateFrameSelectionWithPoint1:p1 point2:p2];
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
            selectionView.hidden = YES;
            // Here you must perform the selection
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        {
            selectionView.hidden = YES;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void) updateFrameSelectionWithPoint1:(CGPoint)p1 point2:(CGPoint)p2
{
    CGRect frameSelection;
    frameSelection.origin.x = fminf(p1.x, p2.x);
    frameSelection.origin.y = fminf(p1.y, p2.y);
    frameSelection.size.width = fabsf(p1.x - p2.x);
    frameSelection.size.height = fabsf(p1.y - p2.y);
    selectionView.frame = frameSelection;
}
```